# How to pass a Class<Descendant> into a Hashmap?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, hashmap

I am populating a HashMap object with pairs of the type 
`<String, Class<Ancestor>>`, where `Ancestor` is some custom class. The idea behind is instantiating an object out of a microservice name.

I am getting a compilation error while putting like this:

**EDITED**

```
map.put("some label", Descendant.class);
```

It is obvious that `HashMap` class expects a real `Ancestor` class and not any `Descendant` class that extends `Ancestor`.

As I have dozens of different descendant classes (microservices), does anybody can tell how to avoid this limitation with HashMap?

I have tried using `Class<?>` instead of `Class<Ancestor>` in the HashMap declaration. But then a casting warning is fired by Eclipse when recalling a microservice

```
Class<Ancestor> a = (Class<Ancestor>) map.get("some label");
```

The strange warning says:

```
Type safety: unchecked cast from Class <capture#151-of ?> to Class <Ancestor>
```

Comment: For that warning, please provide a full [mcve]. Like a simple method where you declare that map, add a value and retrieve that.

Comment: It is a warning at Eclilpse IDE at editing time. I can mute the warning in Eclipse but I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: I know the warning. But again: please read [mcve] really carefully and enhance your question accordingly. You show fractions of code, but that leaves an open room for the things that you have in your code and are not showing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making the generic parameter of `Class` covariant, by using a `HashMap<String, Class<? extends Ancestor>>`.

And you should not cast the `Class` you `get` from the `map` to `Class<Ancestor>`, just use it as a `Class<? extends Ancestor>`:

```
Class<? extends Ancestor> clazz = map.get("...");
```